# How do I restore a broken command string on a command line (BASH) when a message printed to stdout breaks up the command I'm typing?

Tags: bash

If I have a job running in the background, like a very specific grep on a tail of a file, i.e. `tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep -i failure`, output from that command is printed to my terminal, thereby breaking up whatever I'm typing.

This is equivalent to "logging synchronous" in a "vty" or "con" line in a Cisco router.  I know in a Cisco appliance, if "logging synchronous" isn't enabled and you are typing on the terminal, anything that spits out to the terminal interrupts what you're typing.  If you enable "logging synchronous" on your terminal, the message is still spit out but the command string you had been typing is restored immediately to the next line.

In BASH, I though there was a key combination that would restore the command string that was being typed but I can't recall or find out what that key combination is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you were typing is unaltered by output. The only problem is that you can't see it anymore.

There is a readline command, `redraw-current-line`, which will do just as it says, redraw the current line. By default, bash doesn't bind that command to any key sequence, which makes it a bit awkward to use. Bash binds <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> to the `clear-screen` command, which will also redraw the current line, but its side-effect of clearing the screen can be a bit unwelcome.

If you want to enable this feature, you'll need to find some key sequence to bind the command to. For example, you could bind <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> to `redraw-current-line` and use <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> for `clear-screen`. To do that:

```
bind '"\C-l"':redraw-current-line
bind '"\e\C-l"':clear-screen
```

Of course, that's just for experimentation; it will only have effect in the current terminal session. You'll need to put that into your `bash` startup file for it to be sticky.

Comment: This sounds promising.  I'll give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: You can also add `'\e\C-l' : redraw-current-line` to `.inputrc`. Less quoting to worry about, and the binding will be available in all programs using the `readline` library, not just at the `bash` command line.

Comment: My inputrc file now looks like:

# allow redraw-current-line to be tied to esc+ctrl+r
"\e\C-l" : redraw-current-line

# allow the use of the Home/End keys
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line
....
I doesn't seem to do the trick but I will try it on different systems and see if I can get it working.  It's a mix between CentOS, Debian, and Mac OS X.

Comment: @harperville: The `:` must follow the key sequence without a space in between.

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thanks, @rici.  I overlooked that but that's what fixed it.  Very cool!

Answer (score 1):

I usually press <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd>. The disadvantage is it also clears the screen.

Answer (score 1):

My personal solution to that problem is to redirect the output of the background job to a file, eg. 
    tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep -i failure > foo.myout

I'm assuming that's not possible for some reason.  Have you tried control-p?

Comment: Yes, the redirect is an obvious work-around.  CTRL+P almost works.  One time it did, another time it didn't.  Seems like I may not get what I want and I may need to redirect the output to a file.  I thought I saw a colleague hit a key combination and get his command string restored but darn it I know.